# Python saving the last 3 scores

Tags: python, limits

When i run mu code it says :

for line in scoresFile:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

I have tried many things but it won't change the outcome. My code looks like this:

```
SCORE_FILENAME  = "Class1.txt"
MAX_SCORES = 3

try: scoresFile = open('Class1.txt', "r+")
except IOError: scoresFile = open('Class1.txt', "w+") # File not exists
actualScoresTable = []
for line in scoresFile:
        tmp = line.strip().replace("\n","").split(",")

        for index, score in enumerate(tmp[1:]):
            tmp[1+index] = int(score)

        actualScoresTable.append({
                                "name": tmp[0],
                                "scores": tmp[1:],
                                })
        scoresFile.close()

new = True
for index, record in enumerate( actualScoresTable ):
    if record["name"] == pname:
        actualScoresTable[index]["scores"].append(correct)
        if len(record["scores"]) > MAX_SCORES:
            actualScoresTable[index]["scores"].pop(0) # OR del          actualScoresTable[index]["scores"][0]
    new = False
    break
if new:
    actualScoresTable.append({
                            "name": pname,
                            "scores": [correct],
                            })

scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") # Truncating file (write all again)
for record in actualScoresTable:

for index, score in enumerate(record["scores"]):
    record["scores"][index] = str(score)



scoresFile.write( "%s,%s\n" % (record["name"],(record["scores"])) )
scoresFile.close()
```

Can someone help me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem looks to be the `scoresFile.close()` line within the first for loop. If the file is more than one line, then it will be closed by the time you try to access the second line. I think this error will go away if you move that line outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `scoresFile.close()` out of your for loop. You're closing it after reading the first line.

Comment: tmp[1+index] = int(score)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['2']"

Comment: Now you get to actually parse the data in your file. I leave that to you, or you can post another question if you can't figure it out. Try to figure stuff out yourself before asking on SO - it's for your own good!